# Three argument function template confusing example

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>

// maximum of two values of any type:
template<typename T>
T max (T a, T b)
{
    std::cout << "max<T>() \n";
    return b < a ? a : b;
}

// maximum of three values of any type:
template<typename T>
T max (T a, T b, T c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c); // uses the template version even for ints
} //because the following declaration comes
// too late:

// maximum of two int values:
int max (int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "max(int,int) \n";
    return b < a ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    ::max(47,11,33); // OOPS: uses max<T>() instead of max(int,int)
}
```

In this example (from book noted below) I didnt understand **why ::max(47,11,33) call expected to use max(int,int)**. So one is 2 argument another is 3 argument i think it uses 3 argument function definition as it should.

Am I missing something?

Note: David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M. Josuttis, Douglas Gregor    C++ Templates: The Complete Guide [2nd ed.] book

Comment: Play around with the order in which you define your function. For example, what happens if you define (or at least declare) the `int max(int, int)` function before the three-argument template function? Or what if you use *specialization* instead of overloading? Like `template<> int max(int, int);`.

Comment: It's the calls to max(a,b) _inside_ max(a,b,c) that use the template rather than the non-template overload.

Comment: i dont understand the question. the call [does indeed call the 3 parameter function (which in turn calls the 2 parameter one twice)](https://ideone.com/9maVmV).

Comment: @Mat thanks I noticed now.

Comment: @user463035818 the issue is not that it calls max(a, b) twice, but that it calls `max<T>(a, b)` rather than `max(int a, int b)`

Comment: @UKMonkey yes, but arent the comments in the code explaining why this happens?

Comment: @user463035818 yes, but the answer "you're missing reading the comments" doesn't answer the question quite as well

Answer (score 6):

The issue that is being raised is that the non-template overload will not be called.

The `max<T>(T a, T b, T c)` knows about `max<T>(T a, T b)` but DOESN'T know that there's an integer overload because it's declared after it.

Comment: I thought ::max(47,11,33) expected to call two argment definition my confusing from last comment. Maybe "uses" misunderstood with "call"

Comment: @Kad but there are 2 argument definitions; one that's a template, and one that's integer only.  The comments state `// OOPS: uses max<T>() instead of max(int,int)`  showing that they're expecting to call the integer only one, but it doesn't

Comment: This is a consequence of two-phase lookup, correct?

Comment: @UKMonkey I know, I misunerstood first call of 3 argument function call as expected 2 argumented max(int,int).

Comment: @UKMonkey: *"DOESN'T know that there's an integer overload because it's declared after it."* it is more complicated than that, `struct S{}; S max(S, S); max(S{}, S{}, S{});` would correctly call `max(S, S)` version even if declared after.

Answer (score 2):

A solution being: specialize `max<T>`for `T = int` rather than define a `int(int, int)` function:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T max (T a, T b)
{
    std::cout << "max<T>() \n";
    return b < a ? a : b;
}

template<>
int max (int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "max(int,int) \n";
    return b < a ? a : b;
}

template<typename T>
T max (T a, T b, T c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c);
}

int main()
{
    ::max(47,11,33); // BINGO: uses specialized max<int>()
}
```

Output:

```
max(int,int) 
max(int,int)
```

---

This is brittle though, if a non-template function come to use `max<int>` after `max<T>` has been defined and before `max<int>` has been specialized, as per [`[temp.expl.spec]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#6.sentence-1) the program would be ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

If this is a risk you cannot take, there are tools available to you. SFINAE is one of them and could forbid the general `max<T>` to be called with `T = int`. This would lead to either a working program or a compilation error.

Comment: [A major caveat worth mentioning is that the order of the specializations is brittle like this](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#6.sentence-1). This works because the 3 argument version is a template, so the point of instantiation for the 2 argument version being used is in main. But it's easy to add a function in between by accident, breaking the program.

Comment: @StoryTeller indeed.

Comment: It's worse than the non-specialized version being called. It's full on ill-formed NDR. Nasal demons are possible

Comment: No diagnostic required, damn!

Answer (score 1):

`::max(47, 11, 33);` is in fact `::max<int>(47, 11, 33);`

which in turns will call `::max<int>(::max<int>(47, 11), 33);` which might be surprising.

As `int`is a built-in (so no ADL), `max(int, int)` should be visible before `max(T, T, T)` is defined to permit to call that version in template:

With custom type, thanks to ADL, your `max` function could be declared after:

```
template <typename T>
T max (T a, T b)
{
    std::cout << "max<T>()\n";
    return b < a ? a : b;
}

// Should be declared **before** max(T, T, T)
int max(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "max(int,int) \n";
    return b < a ? a : b;
}

template<typename T>
T max (T a, T b, T c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c);
}

struct S {};

// Might be declared after max(T, T, T)
S max(S, S)
{
    std::cout << "max(S, S)\n";
    return {};
}
```

Now, both `max(0, 1, 2)` and `max(s, s, s)` would call internally the non template overload.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/xnIeDB)